# Android emulator ImageView crash

Tags: android

I have add a ImageView and assign a jpg file(a1.jpg), the file is 770Kb. When I run the project, that will Crash and show a lot of error log. I have try another jpg file, the the size is 70KB and run the project, that become no problem. Why? Thanks!

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/Test_string"
    android:src="@drawable/a1" />
```

The error log

```
02-09 12:47:34.692: D/AndroidRuntime(1023): Shutting down VM
02-09 12:47:34.692: W/dalvikvm(1023): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.lighter.androidntest4/com.lighter.androidntest4.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at com.lighter.androidntest4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 11 more
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 24 more
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
02-09 12:47:34.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1023):     ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's probably because you're trying to load too large file. Even your error says so:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

770KB image is quite large for android application. You should really think about something smaller.

You can also increase heap size for your emulator in AVD, but still in your situation it's better to use smaller image if you can.

Comment: 770 KB as it stands isn't that much for most devices, though it will depend greatly on what else you're displaying and have open in memory (and what device). Some older devices support ~20MB whereas newer devices can go to 45-50MB.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... it sounds like your drawable may not be setup correctly. Are you sure about the name etc?

Comment: Also, make sure you are using the right path, so for Android the convention is to have images in res/drawable/*whatever

Answer (score 0):

The emulator cannot support that large an image, as shown by `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. You should be able to customise the emulator to allow larger memory by going into the AVD manager (I believe it is Max VM application heap size).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and Piotr Chojnacki was right; it was a image size issue. I assume that this is more of an issue for older devices and the emulator.